# Detect Swipe in SwipeListView by 47degree

Tags: android, listview

I am using SwipeListView for my Android App. But now i need to detect the swipe action on each row of this list view.

Thank for any help.

**New Update**

i already tried to override the listener or listen on each lsit item when i create them. But all of them are impossible:

I implement listener on each item : holder is ViewHolder. This is a part of code in my Adapter class.

```
holder.frontView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                CLog.d(tag, "Item up");

            }
            CLog.d(tag, "Item Touch " + event.getAction());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It so hard to detect when user swipe the item or scroll the list. the above code always print log "Item touch" when i swipe the items or scroll the list.

Comment: Tell have you tried... and then there will be people to help you..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mSwipeListView
            .setSwipeListViewListener(new com.example.swipelistview.BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
                    //do something
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the onOpened method will be invoked after the view open. I want to block the swipe action on any items of the list. Do you have any others suggestion?

Comment: onStartOpen(int position, int action,boolean right) will be invoked before view opens. But in my case I used onOpened and I put closeAnimate(position) so it gave it a nice animation.

Comment: I never tried this but theoretically you can use device's width to not let the view open. setOffsetRight(int deviceWidth) and setOffsetLeft(int deviceWidth)